# What's wrong with this Javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, syntax

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"dragend",fuction(){
            var newLat = marker.getPosition().lat();
            var newLng = marker.getPosition().lng();
            alert(newLat);

        });
```

If I delete this, everything is fine. If I keep this in here....it says "Missing argument after list", on the first line.

Comment: `fuction()` - is this a typo?

Comment: D'oh, error message is not very helpful, You probably stared at the screen for an hour and didn't see that typo. If you were using a smart JS IDE, it would have pointed out where the error is. PHPStorm did for me.

Comment: I stared at the screen for an hour and could not figure out the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try spelling it `function`